# Indicating Excel cell contains a dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel, validation

I have a list in a cell, however, by default the cell looks empty until a user clicks on it. How can I indicate to a user that the cell contains a dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple simple options I have used many times to indicate there is an input needed.

1. Highlight the cell with color or borders
2. Use a visible comment for that cell

[image]